# How do I use devise sign in/up in a different view as a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, devise, partials

I have my landing page which should contain and login form and a sign up form. I have two buttons of course once the user clicks on one of them it will render the appropriate form. I saw something like that on [railscast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FBxVN7U1Qsk).
[image: This is what I want to achieve]

### Update

I had generated devise views now I want to link those views into my landing page as partials. So that the user will click nicely on the button instead of loading the whole page it will just render the appropriate form.
I hope this makes sense. 
Thanks for the help.

```
<div class="col-md-4 landing-btns">
  <h2>Join us and support the ones in need with every call!</h2>
  <p>All your information will stay private.</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 ">
      <%= link_to 'Register', new_user_registration_path , class: 'btn btn-lg landing-btn' , remote: true , id:'logon'  %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <%= link_to 'Login', new_user_session_path , class: 'btn btn-lg landing-btn' , remote: true , id:'login'  %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <button class="btn btn-social btn-linkedin" >
        <span class="fa fa-linkedin"></span>
        Login with Linkedin
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple.

You just need to pass proper `resource` and `url` in your custom form. Here's an example

```
= form_for(:user, url: session_path(:user)) do |f|
```

Same goes for sign up.

```
= form_for(User.new, url: registration_path(:user)) do |f|
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, I have just updated the question maybe you could help elaborate your answer. Thanks.

Comment: I finally understood what those two lines meant. Thanks a lot.